# Received Memory Warning while stitching images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, image-processing

I am developing an app in which I have to stitch multiple images one by one when ever the user takes picture from camera.

This is what I am using to merge two images.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(joinImages:secondImage:) withObject:firstimage withObject:imageCaptured];

- (UIImage *)joinImages:(UIImage *)im1 secondImage:(UIImage *)im2
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];


    //Joins 2 UIImages together, stitching them horizontally
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(im1.size.width+im2.size.width, im2.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGPoint image1Point = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [im1 drawAtPoint:image1Point];

    CGPoint image2Point = CGPointMake(im1.size.width,0);
    [im2 drawAtPoint:image2Point];

    UIImage* finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    firstimage=finalImage;// final images updated everytime

    [pool release];
    return finalImage;
}
```

But I receive memory warning when I run this in iPhone and it works fine for iPod.

Also images are cropped in case of iPhone.

Anything I can do to resolve this problem.

Thanks..

Comment: are you creating scrollview?

Comment: no there is no scrollview

Comment: are u implementing multiple imageView.?

Comment: No I am just stitching multiple images together again and again and after 3-4 times memory warning comes up.

Comment: try to do this work on other thread. [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector...];

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
 - (UIImage *)joinImages:(UIImage *)im1 secondImage:(UIImage *)im2
   {   
    @autoreleasepool
    {
       //Joins 2 UIImages together, stitching them horizontally
       CGSize size = CGSizeMake(im1.size.width+im2.size.width, im2.size.height);
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

      CGPoint image1Point = CGPointMake(0, 0);
      [im1 drawAtPoint:image1Point];

      CGPoint image2Point = CGPointMake(im1.size.width,0);
      [im2 drawAtPoint:image2Point];

      UIImage* finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
      firstimage=finalImage;// final images updated everytime

      return finalImage;
   }   
 }
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [self joinImages:firstimage secondImage:secondImage];

- (UIImage *)joinImages:(UIImage *)im1 secondImage:(UIImage *)im2
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
//Joins 2 UIImages together, stitching them horizontally
 CGSize size = CGSizeMake(im1.size.width+im2.size.width, im2.size.height);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

 CGPoint image1Point = CGPointMake(0, 0);
 [im1 drawAtPoint:image1Point];

 CGPoint image2Point = CGPointMake(im1.size.width,0);
 [im2 drawAtPoint:image2Point];

 UIImage* finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 firstimage=finalImage;// final images updated everytime

 [pool release];
 return finalImage;
 }
```

Comment: It didn't made any difference in calling the method like this or in perform selector.